# Ошибка при попытке npx prisma migrate dev postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

При попытке выполнить npx prisma migrate dev, вылезает ошибка P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432` .
Вот мой docker-compose файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

схема призмы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в .env файле указан адрес postgresql://admin:admin@localhost:5432/postgres. Я не понимаю почему не может найти бд.